# Trying to use Get-MsolUser to get a list of Microsoft only users in AD but it returns everything

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm using the Get-MsolUser to get a list of all the users in the active directory. However, I just want the user where the Source is "Microsoft" instead of "Windows Server AD". This command does not return the Source nor does it give me the option to filter on the source. This is what I am doing:

```
Connect-MsolService
Connect-AzureAD
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq 'True'} | Format-List | Out-File "C:\Azure Scripts\userlist.txt"
```

Has anybody ever used this or any other command to get a list of only the Microsoft accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following cmdlet:

**Get-MsolUser -All | select userprincipalname,islicensed, {$*.Licenses.AccountSkuId} |Where-Object {$*.isLicensed -eq 'True'}| Format-List | Out-File "C:\Users\azure\Desktop\Get-Msoluserlist.txt"**

Refer : [Get-MsolUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0)

Comment: This also give me a list of everyone. Is there a way to get only users where the "Source = Microsoft Account"? the Get-MsolUser cmdlet returns all other information but it doesn't return the source?

Comment: Also, can I specify which tenant to grab the information from?